# How to check if the array data already exists in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

```js
data = [
    {
        'id': 'asdja',
        'username': 'james',
    },
    {
        'id': 'asqweja',
        'username': 'rhou',
    },
    {
        'id': 'asdqweqj',
        'username': 'arianne'
    },
    {
        'id': 'qpoaksl',
        'username': 'ryan'
    }
];
```

I'm trying to check if `username` already exists.

For example if I input `"james"` then it should display `"Username already exists"`

I try to used find:

```
if (username === data.find((x: any) => x.username === x.username) {
 console.log('Username already exists');
} else {
 console.log('');
}
```

Comment: What have done so far to achieve it?

Comment: @VaritJPatel i try use find then still doesn't work.

Comment: please add whatever you tried to do so far. It helps the community to understand what went wong.

Comment: Answered as per your solution and explain to you what was wrong you're doing.

Comment: @Panda, data.find return null or element, so must be `if (data.find((x: any) => x.username === x.username)`. when you compare object, NOT compare that has the same properties, e.g. `obj={a:10}; obj1={a:10}; bool equals=obj===obj2;` equals is FALSE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Javascript Array `some` for it which returns a boolean when the condition is or isn't met.

```
const inputName = 'james';

// You can use destructuring assignment ({ }) if you only want to use/
// extract a certain property, in our case we will only use the username
const isUserExists = data.some(({ username }) => username === inputName);

console.log(isUserExists);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 'asdja',
        username: 'james',
    },
    {
        id: 'asqweja',
        username: 'rhou',
    },
    {
        id: 'asdqweqj',
        username: 'arianne'
    },
    {
        id: 'qpoaksl',
        username: 'ryan'
    }
];

const user = data.find((x) => x.username === 'james')

if (user) {
 console.log('Username already exists');
} else {
 console.log('');
}
```

The issue is that `find` function returns the first element of the array

Hence, you will get the object back in the response and now you need to check it with the username

```
const user = data.find((x) => x.username === 'james')

if (user) {
 console.log('Username already exists');
} else {
 console.log('');
}
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is lookup the `data` array (which is an array of objects) for a given `username` and want to know if it exists or not. You could simply use `filter()` to see if you get an empty list or not. If it returns an empty list then the username does not exist else it does.

```js
var nameToCheck = 'james'
function checkUsername({username}) {
  return username===nameToCheck
}

var res = data.filter(checkUsername);

console.log(res===[] ? 'Username does not exists!' : 'Username already exists!');
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can also directly check in if condition using `filter`-`length`

```js
const data = [{id:'asdja',username:'james',},{id:'asqweja',username:'rhou',},{id:'asdqweqj',username:'arianne'},{id:'qpoaksl',username:'ryan'}];
let username = 'james';

if (data.filter(({ username }) => username == username).length) {
 console.log('User already exists');
} else {
  console.log('New User');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Another way (**using index**)

```
const username: string = "james";
const idx: number = data.findIndex(obj => obj.username === username);
if (idx > -1) {
// Username already exists.
} else {
// Username does not exists.
```